# Getting a specific number of elements out of a list

Tags: python, arrays, flask

I have the following:

```
# returns a list of all items in ads collection
  
class Vault:
    
  def __init__(self):
    myDate = self.getTodayDate()
    myTime = self.getTodayTime()
    # used to mock collection (table) of ads
    self._ads = [ {
        'id': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'date': myDate,
      'time': myTime,
        'source': 'chron.com',
        'advertiser': 'itunes.apple.com',
        'width': 300,
        'height': 250
    } ]
  def get_all_ads(self):
    return ( ad for ad in self._ads )
  def get_all_adsn(self,n):
    n = int(n)
    if self._ads.__len__()<n:
      return self.get_all_ads()
    max = self._ads[0, n]
    return ( ad for ad in max )
```

It correctly returns when `n` is less than the length of ads. Thus the `get_all_ads` works. The problem is when I try to get a specific number of ads. When I try to get a specific number eg `ads[0, n]` and then do the same thing to get all of the ads out of it I get the following error:

> TypeError
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
>
> From:
> File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/repository/mock.py", line 162, in get_all_adsn max=self._ads[0,n]

`._ads` is a list, why can I not access it? I cast `n` to an `int` (I'm using flask / routes to call this). So if I run `get_all_adsn(2)` I get the correct result, but when I run `get_all_adsn(1)` I get an error.

I don't understand my error, I'm trying to split a list (array, I create it like `[{},{},...]` ) by elements. Why is it talking about a tuple?

Comment: What do you think `self._ads[0,n]` will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code `max = self._ads[0,n]` isn't valid python. The syntax for slicing a list in python is `self._ads[0:n]`, try this instead

```
def get_all_adsn(self,n):
    n=int(n)
    if self._ads.__len__()<n:
        return self.get_all_ads()
    return tuple(self._ads[0:n])
```

P.S. I took the liberty of cleaning up the last two line of your code as well. Actually, python slicing is intelligent enough, that if you slice beyond the upper bound of a sequence (list, tuple, whatever) it just returns the whole sequence anyway. This means you can rewrite the whole function as a simple slice

```
def get_all_adsn(self,n):
    return self._ads[0:int(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `_ads` in your code is a list. And accessing a list thus:

```
_ads[0, 2]
```

has no meaning in Python which is why you see the error. You can confirm this by trying this out in a Python shell:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a_list[0, 2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#108>", line 1, in <module>
    a_list[0, 2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

The reason your code works when you call `get_all_adsn(2)` is because in this case `n` is 2 and it passes this condition in your code:

```
if self._ads.__len__() < n:
```

and hence does not execute the line:

```
max=self._ads[0,n]
```

You might want to change it to:

```
max=self._ads[0:n]
```

Comment: @Blender `>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a_list[0, 2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#108>", line 1, in <module>
    a_list[0, 2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: I deleted my comment because you added "accessing a list".

Answer (score 1):

`l[1, 2]` is the same as `l[(1, 2)]`, which is not what you want. You probably meant to use slicing, which has a different syntax (`l[1:2]`):

```
class Vault:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ads = [{
            'id': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            'date': self.getTodayDate(),
            'time': self.getTodayTime(),
            'source': 'chron.com',
            'advertiser': 'itunes.apple.com',
            'width': 300,
            'height': 250
        }]

    def get_all_ads(self):
        return self.ads

    def get_all_adsn(self, n):
        return self.ads[:n]
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I primarily use Java and python is definitely making me think